# Vaadin 7 Combo Box - how to populate and dropdown when text is typed?

Tags: java, combobox, vaadin7

I have an app that has editors for various database records. These records are referencing each other. I'm developing a new custom data-aware component that is based on ComboBox:

```
public abstract class CustomDbLookupField<T> extends CustomField<T> implements Field<T>
```

Here is what I want:

- the component looks like a combo box (I could do this easily)
- when the corresponding field has a row id value, then the component displays the textual representation of that referenced record (I could also do this)
- when the user starts typing text in the combobox, then I want to search for keywords in the database, and populate the combobox with those items, and let then
- drop down the combo box for him and et him select from the results

I cannot seem to do the last two parts. I wanted to bind listener to the "text typed into combo box" event, but I cannot find any method for that. Moreover, I don't know how to get the text that was just typed in. I was trying this:

```
cmb.addListener(com.vaadin.event.FieldEvents.TextChangeEvent.class,target, method);
```

but I don't know what to pass for parameters target and method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a good question, and one that cannot be answered in a few sentences. I'll try to give you a short answer upfront and will try to elaborate more on this later. I'm currently hacking  a small example to demonstrate the feature you want to achieve. But I'll need some more time. I'll update my answer as soon as I have some results.

Until then, the short answer to your question is that if you register a listener for TextChangeEvents on a component, you'll need someone to actually fire these events. This typically happens on the client side, for example in a `TextField`. When you derive from `CustomField` you still need to provide some client side implemenation. `CustomField` is only a base implementation for your custom field implementation without an awful lot of ready-to-go client side functionality. So, in your case, the listener for `TextChangeEvents` will actually never be invoked.

You can do a lot easier by deriving from ComboBox. ComboBox already has built-in support for prefix filtering when typing in text into the ComboBox. The actual filter functionality is implemented in the `Container` which is data source to the ComboBox. <s>The trick is to overwrite protected method `ComboBox#getOptionsWithFilter(boolean)` to filter in the database and use a custom `Container` implementation which provides the filtered items from the database.</s>

**Update**: As promised, I have written a small demo application which shows how you can write a custom ComboBox whose items are dynamically populated from the database as the user types in text. This can be achieved with a simple hack by deriving from `ComboBox` and overwriting method `com.vaadin.ui.ComboBox.buildFilter(String, FilteringMode)`. The overridden method will need to return a custom `Container.Filter` implementation that simply carries over the current filter String to a custom `com.vaadin.data.Container` implementation. The container is then responsible for fetching the filtered items from the database and populating itself with the query result. In my example, I derive from `BeanItemContainer` where I do the custom database filtering in the overridden method `de.oio.vaadin.SuggestingContainer.addFilter(Filter)`

You can check out the demo at [my GitHub project](https://github.com/rolandkrueger/vaadin-by-example/tree/master/en/ui/SuggestingComboBox). Don't hesitate to ask if there is anything unclear.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because this is the only one, and at least this explains why it was not working. I find it particulary disturbing that anyone can register to any event even if it is invalid for the component. I won't write custom Javascript modules. I end up using PopupButton and a combination of TextField + ListSelect. Doesn't look good but at least it works out of the box.